# GitHub v4 API query for both organizations and users

Tags: github, graphql, github-api, github-graphql

GitHub API v4 does not show the results for companies when `user` query is used. If I use `repositoryOwner` instead, it returns results for both users and companies. However, `user` query can return more detailed information such as biography, website, location etc. which is not included in `repositoryOwner` query.

Is there an alternative option covering all type of users?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access the [`User`](https://developer.github.com/v4/object/user/) or [`Organization`](https://developer.github.com/v4/object/organization/) interface in [`RepositoryOwner`](https://developer.github.com/v4/interface/repositoryowner/) using respectively `... on User` & `... on Organization` :

```graphql
{
  repositoryOwner(login: "google") {
    ... on User {
      avatarUrl
      bio
    }
    ... on Organization {
      name
      members {
        totalCount
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Try it in the explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/?query=%7B%0A%20%20repositoryOwner(login%3A%20%22google%22)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20...%20on%20User%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20avatarUrl%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20bio%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20...%20on%20Organization%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20name%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20members%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20totalCount%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A)

If the result is an organization it will only returns the fields you specifed in `... on Organization` block, if the result is a user it will return the fields specified in `... on User`, in this case as `google` is an organization :

```json
{
  "data": {
    "repositoryOwner": {
      "name": "Google",
      "members": {
        "totalCount": 1656
      }
    }
  }
}
```