# In Github API, how can one distinguish a user from an organisation?

Tags: github, github-api, github-graphql

Take the following Github URL: `https://github.com/google`

How can I determine whether `google` is a user or an organization?

I need to know to this for querying Github's graphql API in the correct way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the login (username) of the user/group, you can use `organization` & `user` to search respectively an organization & a user and check which of the 2 fields is not `null` :

```graphql
{
  org: organization(login: "google") {
    name
    members {
      totalCount
    }
  }
  user: user(login: "google") {
    name
    login
  }
}
```

which gives :

```json
{
  "data": {
    "org": {
      "name": "Google",
      "members": {
        "totalCount": 1677
      }
    },
    "user": null
  }
}
```

or using a variable for `login` input, [try it in the explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/?query=query%20(%24login%3A%20String!)%20%7B%0A%20%20org%3A%20organization(login%3A%20%24login)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20name%0A%20%20%20%20members%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20totalCount%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20user%3A%20user(login%3A%20%24login)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20name%0A%20%20%20%20login%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A&variables=%7B%0A%20%20%22login%22%3A%20%22google%22%0A%7D)

For the Rest API v3, it's much simpler since it doesn't distinguish the user from the organization : https://developer.github.com/v3/users :

```
curl -s 'https://api.github.com/users/google' | jq -r '.type'
```

> Organization

```
curl -s 'https://api.github.com/users/torvalds' | jq -r '.type'
```

> User

Answer (score 0):

Query `repositoryOwner`. Use its `__typename`.

Query:

```
query ($login: String!) {
  repositoryOwner(login: $login) {
    __typename
  }
}
```

Variables:

```json
{"login": "google"}
```

```json
{"login": "torvalds"}
```

Which yields

```json
{
  "data": {
    "repositoryOwner": {
      "__typename": "Organization"
    }
  }
}
```

```json
{
  "data": {
    "repositoryOwner": {
      "__typename": "User"
    }
  }
}
```

If you are looking for some common properties, and don't care whether the subject is a user or an organization. You can try something like:

```
query ($login: String!) {
  repositoryOwner(login: $login) {
    avatarUrl
  }
}
```

You may want to use another common ancestor interface for properties that `repositoryOwner` lacks:

```
query ($login: String!) {
  repositoryOwner(login: $login) {
    ... on ProfileOwner {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

Even dispatch to different fields depending on the concrete object type: (credited to [Bertrand Martel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2614364/bertrand-martel)'s another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48130222/4379906))

```
query ($login: String!) {
  repositoryOwner(login: $login) {    
    ... on User {
      bio
    }
    ... on Organization {
      description
    }
  }
}
```

The all-in-one combination,

```
query ($login: String!) {
  repositoryOwner(login: $login) {
    avatarUrl
    
    ... on ProfileOwner {
      name
    }
    
    ... on User {
      bio
    }
    ... on Organization {
      description
    }
  }
}
```

providing the following variables,

```json
{"login": "microsoft"}
```

```json
{"login": "munificent"}
```

yields:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "repositoryOwner": {
      "avatarUrl": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/6154722?v=4",
      "name": "Microsoft",
      "description": "Open source projects and samples from Microsoft"
    }
  }
}
```

```json
{
  "data": {
    "repositoryOwner": {
      "avatarUrl": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/46275?v=4",
      "name": "Bob Nystrom",
      "bio": "Programming language developer, ex-game developer, UI nerd, author of \"Game Programming Patterns\" and \"Crafting Interpreters\"."
    }
  }
}
```